# How to make a code not create only first window if .json file already exists in python?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to write a program in Python using customtkinter that emulates key presses for one game. I have set it up so that at the start of the program, a .json file with the keys specified by the user in comboboxes as the keys they use in the game is created. My question is, how can I make it so that if the keybinds.json file already exists, the app = customtkinter.CTk will not be created, but instead "w = customtkinter.CTk" will be created and the .json file will be read there? Here is the code:

```
import tkinter
import customtkinter
import keyboard
from time import sleep
import json
import os

customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("dark")  # Modes: system (default), light, dark
customtkinter.set_default_color_theme("dark-blue")  # Themes: blue (default), dark-blue, green

app = customtkinter.CTk()  # create CTk window like you do with the Tk window
app.geometry("600x480")
app.resizable(False, False)
app.title("Keybinds for ENigma")
screen_width = app.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = app.winfo_screenheight()

x_coordinate = (screen_width/2) - (600/2)
y_coordinate = (screen_height/2) - (440/2)

def submit():
    keybinds = {
        "Jump": JumpKey.get(),
        "Aim Up": AIMUp.get(),
        "Move Up": UPMoveKey.get(),
        "Move Left": LEFTMoveKey.get(),
        "Move Right": RIGHTMoveKey.get(),
        "Move Down": DOWNMoveKey.get(),
        "Light Attack": LIGHTATTACKKey.get(),
        "Heavy Attack": HEAVYATTACKKey.get(),
        "Dodge": DodgeKey.get()
    }
    
    with open("keybinds.json", "w") as file:
        json.dump(keybinds, file)
    app.destroy()
    w=customtkinter.CTk()
    w.geometry("620x580")
    w.title('Enigma v0.1')
    w.resizable(False, False)
    screen_width = w.winfo_screenwidth()
    screen_height = w.winfo_screenheight()

    x_coordinate = (screen_width/2) - (620/2)
    y_coordinate = (screen_height/2) - (580/2)


    with open("./keybinds.json") as f:
        keybindData = json.load(f)

    JUMP = keybindData["Jump"]
    AIMUP = keybindData["Aim Up"]
    UP = keybindData["Move Up"]
    LEFT = keybindData["Move Left"]
    RIGHT = keybindData["Move Right"]
    DOWN = keybindData["Move Down"]
    LightAttack = keybindData["Light Attack"]
    HeavyAttack = keybindData["Heavy Attack"]
    DODGE = keybindData["Dodge"]

    w.geometry("+%d+%d" % (x_coordinate, y_coordinate))
    l1=customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=w, text=f"Welcome to Enigma v0.1!", font=('Century Gothic', 35))
    l1.place(x=320, y=25, anchor=tkinter.CENTER)

    # names
    blasters=customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=w, text="Blasters", font=('Century Gothic', 20))
    blasters.place(x=75, y=100)

    #################
    # blasters
    
    cmb1=customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=w, text="DLightDAir", font=('Century Gothic', 14))
    cmb1.place(x=30, y=147)

    cmb2=customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=w, text="DLightSAir", font=('Century Gothic', 14))
    cmb2.place(x=30, y=177)

    cmb3=customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=w, text="DLight Recovery", font=('Century Gothic', 14))
    cmb3.place(x=2, y=203)
   
    ###################
    # trigger keys
    # blasters
    TriggerKey1 = customtkinter.StringVar(None)
    WeaponKeyCombox1 = customtkinter.CTkComboBox(master=w, width=70, height=20, variable=TriggerKey1, values=['None', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', 'Down', 'DOWN', 'Up', 'UP', 'Left', 'LEFT', 'Right', 'RIGHT', 'Shift', 'SHIFT', 'Ctrl', 'CTRL', 'Esc', 'ESC', 'Alt', 'ALT', 'Space', 'SPACE', 'Enter', 'ENTER','Spacebar', 'SPACEBAR', 'Tab', 'TAB', 'Home', 'HOME', 'End', 'END', 'Plus', 'PLUS', 'Minus', 'MINUS', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'Up arrow key', 'Down arrow key', 'Left arrow key', 'Right arrow key'])
    WeaponKeyCombox1.set('None')
    WeaponKeyCombox1.place(x=115,y=150)

    TriggerKey2 = customtkinter.StringVar(None)
    WeaponKeyCombox2 = customtkinter.CTkComboBox(master=w, width=70, height=20, variable=TriggerKey2, values=['None', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', 'Down', 'DOWN', 'Up', 'UP', 'Left', 'LEFT', 'Right', 'RIGHT', 'Shift', 'SHIFT', 'Ctrl', 'CTRL', 'Esc', 'ESC', 'Alt', 'ALT', 'Space', 'SPACE', 'Enter', 'ENTER','Spacebar', 'SPACEBAR', 'Tab', 'TAB', 'Home', 'HOME', 'End', 'END', 'Plus', 'PLUS', 'Minus', 'MINUS', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'Up arrow key', 'Down arrow key', 'Left arrow key', 'Right arrow key'])
    WeaponKeyCombox2.set('None')
    WeaponKeyCombox2.place(x=115,y=180)

    TriggerKey3 = customtkinter.StringVar(None)
    WeaponKeyCombox3 = customtkinter.CTkComboBox(master=w, width=70, height=20, variable=TriggerKey3, values=['None', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', 'Down', 'DOWN', 'Up', 'UP', 'Left', 'LEFT', 'Right', 'RIGHT', 'Shift', 'SHIFT', 'Ctrl', 'CTRL', 'Esc', 'ESC', 'Alt', 'ALT', 'Space', 'SPACE', 'Enter', 'ENTER','Spacebar', 'SPACEBAR', 'Tab', 'TAB', 'Home', 'HOME', 'End', 'END', 'Plus', 'PLUS', 'Minus', 'MINUS', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'Up arrow key', 'Down arrow key', 'Left arrow key', 'Right arrow key'])
    WeaponKeyCombox3.set('None')
    WeaponKeyCombox3.place(x=115,y=210)

    def DLightDAirBlasters(event):
        if event.name == TriggerKey1.get():
            keyboard.press(DOWN)
            keyboard.press_and_release(LightAttack)
            keyboard.release(DOWN)
            sleep(0.69)
            keyboard.press(DOWN)
            keyboard.press_and_release(DODGE)
            keyboard.press_and_release(JUMP)
            keyboard.press_and_release(LightAttack)
            keyboard.release(DOWN)
    keyboard.on_press(DLightDAirBlasters)

    w.mainloop()
    

AIMUp = customtkinter.StringVar(None)
AIMUp = customtkinter.CTkComboBox(master=app, width=100, corner_radius=10, height=30, values=['None', 'w', 'a', 's', 'd', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'i', 'up', 'down', 'left', 'right'])
AIMUp.set('None')
AIMUp.place(x=230,y=80)

UPMoveKey = customtkinter.StringVar(None)
UPMoveKey = customtkinter.CTkComboBox(master=app, width=100, corner_radius=10, height=30, values=['None', 'w', 'a', 's', 'd', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'i', 'up', 'down', 'left', 'right'])
UPMoveKey.set('None')
UPMoveKey.place(x=250,y=120)

LEFTMoveKey = customtkinter.StringVar(None)
LEFTMoveKey = customtkinter.CTkComboBox(master=app, corner_radius=10, width=100, height=30, values=['None', 'w', 'a', 's', 'd', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'i', 'up', 'down', 'left', 'right'])
LEFTMoveKey.set('None')
LEFTMoveKey.place(x=250,y=160)

RIGHTMoveKey = customtkinter.StringVar(None)
RIGHTMoveKey = customtkinter.CTkComboBox(master=app, corner_radius=10, width=100, height=30, values=['None', 'w', 'a', 's', 'd', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'i', 'up', 'down', 'left', 'right'])
RIGHTMoveKey.set('None')
RIGHTMoveKey.place(x=250,y=200)

DOWNMoveKey = customtkinter.StringVar(None)
DOWNMoveKey = customtkinter.CTkComboBox(master=app, corner_radius=10, width=100, height=30, values=['None', 'w', 'a', 's', 'd', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'i', 'up', 'down', 'left', 'right'])
DOWNMoveKey.set('None')
DOWNMoveKey.place(x=250,y=240)

LIGHTATTACKKey = customtkinter.StringVar(None)
LIGHTATTACKKey = customtkinter.CTkComboBox(master=app, corner_radius=10, width=100, height=30, values=['None', 'w', 'a', 's', 'd', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'i', 'c', 'x', 'z', 'v', 'b', 'n', 'm'])
LIGHTATTACKKey.set('None')
LIGHTATTACKKey.place(x=250,y=280)

HEAVYATTACKKey = customtkinter.StringVar(None)
HEAVYATTACKKey = customtkinter.CTkComboBox(master=app, corner_radius=10, width=100, height=30, values=['None', 'w', 'a', 's', 'd', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'i', 'c', 'x', 'z', 'v', 'b', 'n', 'm'])
HEAVYATTACKKey.set('None')
HEAVYATTACKKey.place(x=250,y=320)

DodgeKey = customtkinter.StringVar(None)
DodgeKey = customtkinter.CTkComboBox(master=app, corner_radius=10, width=100, height=30, values=['None', 'w', 'a', 's', 'd', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'i', 'c', 'x', 'z', 'v', 'b', 'n', 'm'])
DodgeKey.set('None')
DodgeKey.place(x=250,y=360)

JumpKey = customtkinter.StringVar(None)
JumpKey = customtkinter.CTkComboBox(master=app, corner_radius=10, width=100, height=30, values=['None', 'up', 'down', 'left', 'right', 'space', 'w', 'a', 's', 'd', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'i', 'c', 'x', 'z', 'v', 'b', 'n', 'm'])
JumpKey.set('None')
JumpKey.place(x=250,y=400)

label1 = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=app, text="Define the keys you use for input in game", font=('Century Gothic', 25))
label1.place(x=310, y=50, anchor=tkinter.CENTER)

labelaimup = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=app, text="Aim Up: ", font=('Century Gothic', 15))
labelaimup.place(x=160, y=80)

labelaimup2 = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=app, text="You must bind the Aim Up key in game!", font=('Century Gothic', 13))
labelaimup2.place(x=340, y=80)

labelup = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=app, text="Move Up: ", font=('Century Gothic', 15))
labelup.place(x=150, y=120)

labelleft = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=app, text="Move Left: ", font=('Century Gothic', 15))
labelleft.place(x=150, y=160)

labelright = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=app, text="Move Right: ", font=('Century Gothic', 15))
labelright.place(x=150, y=200)

labeldown = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=app, text="Move Down: ", font=('Century Gothic', 15))
labeldown.place(x=140, y=240)

labellightattack = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=app, text="Light Attack: ", font=('Century Gothic', 15))
labellightattack.place(x=150, y=280)

labelheavyattack = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=app, text="Heavy Attack: ", font=('Century Gothic', 15))
labelheavyattack.place(x=135, y=320)

labeldodge = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=app, text="Dodge/Dash: ", font=('Century Gothic', 15))
labeldodge.place(x=135, y=360)

labeljump = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=app, text="Jump: ", font=('Century Gothic', 15))
labeljump.place(x=175, y=400)

button = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=app, text="Submit", corner_radius=10, width=50, command=submit)
button.place(x=260, y=445)

app.geometry("+%d+%d" % (x_coordinate, y_coordinate))

app.mainloop()
```

i dont know what to try

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because if the person wrote the actual code - how on earth he doesnt know how to do if/else check ?

Comment: im newbie, this code is pretty simple, i just dont know how to do this

Answer (score 0):

If statement at the end inserted and loading from there, passing loaded data to `submit`. However, `app` still gets created and destroyed. You will have to refactor your code to smaller functions and call them appropriately to avoid this.

```
import tkinter
import customtkinter
import keyboard
from time import sleep
import json
from os.path import exists

customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("dark")  # Modes: system (default), light, dark
customtkinter.set_default_color_theme("dark-blue")  # Themes: blue (default), dark-blue, green

app = customtkinter.CTk()  # create CTk window like you do with the Tk window
app.geometry("600x480")
app.resizable(False, False)
app.title("Keybinds for ENigma")
screen_width = app.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = app.winfo_screenheight()

x_coordinate = (screen_width / 2) - (600 / 2)
y_coordinate = (screen_height / 2) - (440 / 2)


def submit(keys=None):
    if not keys:
        keybinds = {
            "Jump": JumpKey.get(),
            "Aim Up": AIMUp.get(),
            "Move Up": UPMoveKey.get(),
            "Move Left": LEFTMoveKey.get(),
            "Move Right": RIGHTMoveKey.get(),
            "Move Down": DOWNMoveKey.get(),
            "Light Attack": LIGHTATTACKKey.get(),
            "Heavy Attack": HEAVYATTACKKey.get(),
            "Dodge": DodgeKey.get()
        }
    else:
        keybinds = keys

    with open("keybinds.json", "w") as file:
        json.dump(keybinds, file)
    app.destroy()
    w = customtkinter.CTk()
    w.geometry("620x580")
    w.title('Enigma v0.1')
    w.resizable(False, False)
    screen_width = w.winfo_screenwidth()
    screen_height = w.winfo_screenheight()

    x_coordinate = (screen_width / 2) - (620 / 2)
    y_coordinate = (screen_height / 2) - (580 / 2)

    with open("./keybinds.json") as f:
        keybindData = json.load(f)

    JUMP = keybindData["Jump"]
    AIMUP = keybindData["Aim Up"]
    UP = keybindData["Move Up"]
    LEFT = keybindData["Move Left"]
    RIGHT = keybindData["Move Right"]
    DOWN = keybindData["Move Down"]
    LightAttack = keybindData["Light Attack"]
    HeavyAttack = keybindData["Heavy Attack"]
    DODGE = keybindData["Dodge"]

    w.geometry("+%d+%d" % (x_coordinate, y_coordinate))
    l1 = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=w, text=f"Welcome to Enigma v0.1!", font=('Century Gothic', 35))
    l1.place(x=320, y=25, anchor=tkinter.CENTER)

    # names
    blasters = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=w, text="Blasters", font=('Century Gothic', 20))
    blasters.place(x=75, y=100)

    #################
    # blasters

    cmb1 = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=w, text="DLightDAir", font=('Century Gothic', 14))
    cmb1.place(x=30, y=147)

    cmb2 = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=w, text="DLightSAir", font=('Century Gothic', 14))
    cmb2.place(x=30, y=177)

    cmb3 = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=w, text="DLight Recovery", font=('Century Gothic', 14))
    cmb3.place(x=2, y=203)

    ###################
    # trigger keys
    # blasters
    TriggerKey1 = customtkinter.StringVar(None)
    WeaponKeyCombox1 = customtkinter.CTkComboBox(master=w, width=70, height=20, variable=TriggerKey1,
                                                 values=['None', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k',
                                                         'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w',
                                                         'x', 'y', 'z', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
                                                         '0', 'Down', 'DOWN', 'Up', 'UP', 'Left', 'LEFT', 'Right',
                                                         'RIGHT', 'Shift', 'SHIFT', 'Ctrl', 'CTRL', 'Esc', 'ESC', 'Alt',
                                                         'ALT', 'Space', 'SPACE', 'Enter', 'ENTER', 'Spacebar',
                                                         'SPACEBAR', 'Tab', 'TAB', 'Home', 'HOME', 'End', 'END', 'Plus',
                                                         'PLUS', 'Minus', 'MINUS', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G',
                                                         'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S',
                                                         'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'Up arrow key',
                                                         'Down arrow key', 'Left arrow key', 'Right arrow key'])
    WeaponKeyCombox1.set('None')
    WeaponKeyCombox1.place(x=115, y=150)

    TriggerKey2 = customtkinter.StringVar(None)
    WeaponKeyCombox2 = customtkinter.CTkComboBox(master=w, width=70, height=20, variable=TriggerKey2,
                                                 values=['None', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k',
                                                         'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w',
                                                         'x', 'y', 'z', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
                                                         '0', 'Down', 'DOWN', 'Up', 'UP', 'Left', 'LEFT', 'Right',
                                                         'RIGHT', 'Shift', 'SHIFT', 'Ctrl', 'CTRL', 'Esc', 'ESC', 'Alt',
                                                         'ALT', 'Space', 'SPACE', 'Enter', 'ENTER', 'Spacebar',
                                                         'SPACEBAR', 'Tab', 'TAB', 'Home', 'HOME', 'End', 'END', 'Plus',
                                                         'PLUS', 'Minus', 'MINUS', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G',
                                                         'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S',
                                                         'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'Up arrow key',
                                                         'Down arrow key', 'Left arrow key', 'Right arrow key'])
    WeaponKeyCombox2.set('None')
    WeaponKeyCombox2.place(x=115, y=180)

    TriggerKey3 = customtkinter.StringVar(None)
    WeaponKeyCombox3 = customtkinter.CTkComboBox(master=w, width=70, height=20, variable=TriggerKey3,
                                                 values=['None', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k',
                                                         'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w',
                                                         'x', 'y', 'z', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
                                                         '0', 'Down', 'DOWN', 'Up', 'UP', 'Left', 'LEFT', 'Right',
                                                         'RIGHT', 'Shift', 'SHIFT', 'Ctrl', 'CTRL', 'Esc', 'ESC', 'Alt',
                                                         'ALT', 'Space', 'SPACE', 'Enter', 'ENTER', 'Spacebar',
                                                         'SPACEBAR', 'Tab', 'TAB', 'Home', 'HOME', 'End', 'END', 'Plus',
                                                         'PLUS', 'Minus', 'MINUS', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G',
                                                         'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S',
                                                         'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'Up arrow key',
                                                         'Down arrow key', 'Left arrow key', 'Right arrow key'])
    WeaponKeyCombox3.set('None')
    WeaponKeyCombox3.place(x=115, y=210)

    def DLightDAirBlasters(event):
        if event.name == TriggerKey1.get():
            keyboard.press(DOWN)
            keyboard.press_and_release(LightAttack)
            keyboard.release(DOWN)
            sleep(0.69)
            keyboard.press(DOWN)
            keyboard.press_and_release(DODGE)
            keyboard.press_and_release(JUMP)
            keyboard.press_and_release(LightAttack)
            keyboard.release(DOWN)

    #keyboard.on_press(DLightDAirBlasters)

    w.mainloop()


AIMUp = customtkinter.StringVar(None)
AIMUp = customtkinter.CTkComboBox(master=app, width=100, corner_radius=10, height=30,
                                  values=['None', 'w', 'a', 's', 'd', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'i', 'up', 'down', 'left',
                                          'right'])
AIMUp.set('None')
AIMUp.place(x=230, y=80)

UPMoveKey = customtkinter.StringVar(None)
UPMoveKey = customtkinter.CTkComboBox(master=app, width=100, corner_radius=10, height=30,
                                      values=['None', 'w', 'a', 's', 'd', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'i', 'up', 'down', 'left',
                                              'right'])
UPMoveKey.set('None')
UPMoveKey.place(x=250, y=120)

LEFTMoveKey = customtkinter.StringVar(None)
LEFTMoveKey = customtkinter.CTkComboBox(master=app, corner_radius=10, width=100, height=30,
                                        values=['None', 'w', 'a', 's', 'd', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'i', 'up', 'down', 'left',
                                                'right'])
LEFTMoveKey.set('None')
LEFTMoveKey.place(x=250, y=160)

RIGHTMoveKey = customtkinter.StringVar(None)
RIGHTMoveKey = customtkinter.CTkComboBox(master=app, corner_radius=10, width=100, height=30,
                                         values=['None', 'w', 'a', 's', 'd', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'i', 'up', 'down', 'left',
                                                 'right'])
RIGHTMoveKey.set('None')
RIGHTMoveKey.place(x=250, y=200)

DOWNMoveKey = customtkinter.StringVar(None)
DOWNMoveKey = customtkinter.CTkComboBox(master=app, corner_radius=10, width=100, height=30,
                                        values=['None', 'w', 'a', 's', 'd', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'i', 'up', 'down', 'left',
                                                'right'])
DOWNMoveKey.set('None')
DOWNMoveKey.place(x=250, y=240)

LIGHTATTACKKey = customtkinter.StringVar(None)
LIGHTATTACKKey = customtkinter.CTkComboBox(master=app, corner_radius=10, width=100, height=30,
                                           values=['None', 'w', 'a', 's', 'd', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'i', 'c', 'x', 'z', 'v',
                                                   'b', 'n', 'm'])
LIGHTATTACKKey.set('None')
LIGHTATTACKKey.place(x=250, y=280)

HEAVYATTACKKey = customtkinter.StringVar(None)
HEAVYATTACKKey = customtkinter.CTkComboBox(master=app, corner_radius=10, width=100, height=30,
                                           values=['None', 'w', 'a', 's', 'd', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'i', 'c', 'x', 'z', 'v',
                                                   'b', 'n', 'm'])
HEAVYATTACKKey.set('None')
HEAVYATTACKKey.place(x=250, y=320)

DodgeKey = customtkinter.StringVar(None)
DodgeKey = customtkinter.CTkComboBox(master=app, corner_radius=10, width=100, height=30,
                                     values=['None', 'w', 'a', 's', 'd', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'i', 'c', 'x', 'z', 'v', 'b',
                                             'n', 'm'])
DodgeKey.set('None')
DodgeKey.place(x=250, y=360)

JumpKey = customtkinter.StringVar(None)
JumpKey = customtkinter.CTkComboBox(master=app, corner_radius=10, width=100, height=30,
                                    values=['None', 'up', 'down', 'left', 'right', 'space', 'w', 'a', 's', 'd', 'j',
                                            'k', 'l', 'i', 'c', 'x', 'z', 'v', 'b', 'n', 'm'])
JumpKey.set('None')
JumpKey.place(x=250, y=400)

label1 = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=app, text="Define the keys you use for input in game",
                                font=('Century Gothic', 25))
label1.place(x=310, y=50, anchor=tkinter.CENTER)

labelaimup = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=app, text="Aim Up: ", font=('Century Gothic', 15))
labelaimup.place(x=160, y=80)

labelaimup2 = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=app, text="You must bind the Aim Up key in game!",
                                     font=('Century Gothic', 13))
labelaimup2.place(x=340, y=80)

labelup = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=app, text="Move Up: ", font=('Century Gothic', 15))
labelup.place(x=150, y=120)

labelleft = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=app, text="Move Left: ", font=('Century Gothic', 15))
labelleft.place(x=150, y=160)

labelright = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=app, text="Move Right: ", font=('Century Gothic', 15))
labelright.place(x=150, y=200)

labeldown = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=app, text="Move Down: ", font=('Century Gothic', 15))
labeldown.place(x=140, y=240)

labellightattack = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=app, text="Light Attack: ", font=('Century Gothic', 15))
labellightattack.place(x=150, y=280)

labelheavyattack = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=app, text="Heavy Attack: ", font=('Century Gothic', 15))
labelheavyattack.place(x=135, y=320)

labeldodge = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=app, text="Dodge/Dash: ", font=('Century Gothic', 15))
labeldodge.place(x=135, y=360)

labeljump = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=app, text="Jump: ", font=('Century Gothic', 15))
labeljump.place(x=175, y=400)

button = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=app, text="Submit", corner_radius=10, width=50, command=submit)
button.place(x=260, y=445)

app.geometry("+%d+%d" % (x_coordinate, y_coordinate))

if exists('keybinds.json'):
    with open("./keybinds.json") as f:
        keybindData = json.load(f)
    submit(keybindData)

app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to give an idea, this is an example using two windows inheriting from tkinter.Toplevel.

```
import tkinter as tk
import os
import json

class MainWindow(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, master, keybinds):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.title('Main Window')
        self.geometry('300x50')

        self.keybinds = keybinds

        tk.Label(self, text=f'Keybinds :\n{self.keybinds}').pack()

        # clicking on the button destroys root and automatically destroys this window
        tk.Button(self, text='Quit', command=self.master.destroy).pack()

class SettingsDialog(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.title('Keybinds Settings')
        self.geometry('300x50')

        self.keybinds = ''

        # load all keybinds widgets here
        tk.Label(self, text='Put all the keybinds widgets here\nHere we just set "Jump" to "F1"').pack()

        tk.Button(self, text='Submit', command=self.submit).pack()

    def submit(self):
        # read the real keybinds from widgets
        self.keybinds = self.create_dummy_keybinds()
        self.destroy()
        

    def create_dummy_keybinds(self):
        return {
        "Jump": 'F1'
        }

def main():

    root = tk.Tk()
    # hide root window
    root.withdraw()

    file_is_present = os.path.isfile('keybinds.json')

    if not file_is_present:
        # open settings dialog, activate it and wait for it to close
        settings_dialog = SettingsDialog(root)
        settings_dialog.grab_set()
        settings_dialog.wait_window()

        # dialog has been closed - read dialog data and save it to the file
        if settings_dialog.keybinds:
            with open("keybinds.json", "w") as file:
                json.dump(settings_dialog.keybinds, file)
            file_is_present = True

    if file_is_present:
        # read data from file
        key_bind_data = {}
        with open("./keybinds.json") as f:
            key_bind_data = json.load(f)

        # display main window passing data as argument
        main_window = MainWindow(root, key_bind_data)        
        main_window.mainloop()

    root.mainloop()

    

if __name__ == '__main__':    
    main()
```